# separate dataframe into individual columns with its own index

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                   Arrows :Current    Arrows:previous 1M    Arrows:previous 2M
silverine               1                0                    0
fire                    2                2                    2
ice                    11               12                   10
wind                    4                4                    4
poisonous               2                2                    9
```

Supposing that I do not know how many columns I have I would like to obtain each column independiently with the index.

The desired output would look something like this:

```
                   Arrows :Current 
silverine               1         
fire                    2         
ice                    11            
wind                    4                
poisonous               2              


                   Arrows:previous 1M 
silverine               0  
fire                    2         
ice                    12           
wind                    4           
poisonous               2

                  Arrows:previous 2M
silverine                0
fire                     2
ice                     10
wind                     4
poisonous                9
```

Is there any defined  property in pandas to obtain each column with the index ?

Comment: I am not sure if understand - what is desired output? `list`? Or need loop by columns? Can you explain more? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need select data by columns to `Series`, what is each column of `DataFrame` with same `index` as `df`.

If need list of all Series:

```
L = [df[col] for col in df.columns]
print (L)
[silverine     1
fire          2
ice          11
wind          4
poisonous     2
Name: Arrows :Current, dtype: int64, silverine     0
fire          2
ice          12
wind          4
poisonous     2
Name: Arrows:previous 1M, dtype: int64, silverine     0
fire          2
ice          10
wind          4
poisonous     9
Name: Arrows:previous 2M, dtype: int64]
```

It need only loop by all columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print (df[col])
silverine     1
fire          2
ice          11
wind          4
poisonous     2
Name: Arrows :Current, dtype: int64
silverine     0
fire          2
ice          12
wind          4
poisonous     2
Name: Arrows:previous 1M, dtype: int64
silverine     0
fire          2
ice          10
wind          4
poisonous     9
Name: Arrows:previous 2M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael thanks again for your help , How could I obtain the output otherway than by a list in order to turn it into a json?

Comment: Give me a sec please.

Comment: I think best is use `df.to_json('file.json',orient='split')` and then for read data `df = pd.read_json('file.jon', orient='split')`

Comment: Thank you Jezrael!